# WCF: There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network. asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I am using `wcf` for my project but when I upload something I get the following error(error is coming only for 1 time and then it works fine until I rebuild the project)

```
using (System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(fi.FullName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
{
    uploadRequestInfo.FileServerId = item.FileServerId;
    uploadRequestInfo.FileName = item.FileName;
    uploadRequestInfo.FileExtension = item.FileExtension;
    uploadRequestInfo.Length = fi.Length;
    uploadRequestInfo.FileByteStream = stream;

    Utils.Logger.Instance.LogActivity("Document", "upload", "started");
    fs.UploadFileStream(uploadRequestInfo.FileExtension, uploadRequestInfo.FileName, uploadRequestInfo.FileServerId, uploadRequestInfo.Length, stream);
    Utils.Logger.Instance.LogActivity("Document", "Save", "completed");
}
```

when I debug my code the below function executed properly without throwing any exception

```
fs.UploadFileStream(uploadRequestInfo.FileExtension, uploadRequestInfo.FileName, uploadRequestInfo.FileServerId, uploadRequestInfo.Length, stream);
```

but still the error comes, and more confusingly the error come only 1 time, what can be the issue here?

Comment: What does this question have to do with asp.net or WCF? I can see no evidence of them being involved from the information provided.

Comment: @TomW this is wcf service and I did not mention asp.net(I mention asp.net mvc) which i am using in the project

Comment: _I get the following error_ - and the error message is what? Can you edit it into your question? (as text please, not as an image)

Comment: I can't find any evidence of the method `UploadFileStream` in documentation - where is this from? It must be an extension method because it [doesn't exist on FileStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream). Where is WCF involved? What's your WCF binding configuration? Where is asp.net MVC involved? What data are you sending in the file you are opening? There is nothing like enough information here to be able to answer.